# Rails Bootstrap 4, dropdown stops working after pressing back button on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm using Ruby on Rails 6, and I'm importing bootstrap from the `application.html.erb` file.

The dropdown stops working when I press the back button on the browser.

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
    'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> 
    </head>
    
    <body>
       <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
         </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
```

dropdown before click
[image: Dropdown before clicking it]

dropdown after click
[image: Dropdown after clicking it]

Dropdown after clicking, having previously gone back using the browser button. The values don't change.
[image: Dropdown after clicking, having previously gone back using the browser button]

Using the debugger, I get this compiler error

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': The
> provided selector is empty.

Comment: In the last screenshot the `button` tag isn't expanded

Comment: And what do you mean by "stops working"?  Does it no longer drop down?  Does it no longer have options?

Comment: It doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the bootstrap script import in `<head>`. Script may reload if in the `<body>` when you back into the page causing issues.